# wxPythonでListBoxの先頭に項目を追加したい

Tags: python

wxPythonでListBoxの先頭に項目を追加したいのですが、Googleやドキュメント等で調べても方法が見つかりません。
どのようにすれば先頭に項目を追加できるでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pos`に`0`を指定して[InsertItems](http://wxwindowsjp.osdn.jp/docs/html/wx/wx233.htm#wxlistboxinsertitems)を呼び出すことで先頭に項目を追加できませんか？